# WordPress hooks for executing right before any action or page loading

Tags: php, wordpress, action, hook

I'm quite new to WP. Task is to develop a plugin for oauth authentication on one of not popular openID providers. I did the same for CodeIgniter project, but WP is a CMS and is little bit complex for me to understand. In Codeigniter i check authorisation before each action. In WP i need a hook which uses for it... before each page printing, or maybe.. it would be right to say before each action in terms of frameworks. What is this hook's name?

Comment: Check this http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference and this http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference for all of the hooks. You can also create your own hooks , for that check http://archive.extralogical.net/2007/06/wphooks/ , http://wpengineer.com/1302/define-your-own-wordpress-hooks/, http://sandeepthemaster.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/198/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of all available hooks can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Information about Hooks: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters

Other hooks must be suggested and will be added in a future release if is a good suggestion.
Or you'd have to edit the core files ;)

Comment: I browsed these pages in Codex before questioning here. And couldn't find any suitable hook. I need smth which will be executing right before any action(in terms of frameworks).

Comment: Why should you need to execute that b4 any action? just to get the point, you want to run the check at the beginning of everything... not run it once before every possible action (1000times ;) ), if you want to run it at the earliest point possible I suggest loop_start or init

Comment: maybe some hook is available for calling before loading every page?

Comment: How about muplugins_loaded After must-use plugins are loaded (this is the earliest hook you could use, [the order of the hooks is the order in which they are called)

Comment: This hook is used before loading each page?

Comment: or just one time in first visit of user?

Comment: Each time you send a request to the server (klick a link, change page etc), so as you said before loading the page, every time!

Answer (score 21):

Last hook before loading the template is  **template_redirect**

You can use it like this:

```
function my_function(){
    // your code goes here
}
add_action( "template_redirect", "my_function" );
```

Comment: I don't know why but "init" hook are executing two times, and "template_redirect" run just one, thanks.

Comment: Marc, does this also work when utilizing a page builder like Elementor?

Comment: Rafael, I haven't used Wordpress since 2017. I'm not even sure what a Page Builder is. In general this hook is used to add some functionality at a specific moment when loading the page. In this case it is the last moment that you can add functionality in the request pipeline. I'm afraid that I can't help you further than that.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `init` hook. It will be performed before element or HTML code. It's also useful to manage POST and GET variables. The syntax is something like this:

```
function yourfunction() {
    dosomething();
}
add_action('init', 'yourfunction');
```

Comment: The second parameter is a string. Perhaps this has changed since this answer.

Comment: I voted this down because there is a hook that fires "right before" page loading and it's not "init". It is "template_redirect". I created a new answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

You mean a hook when all wordpress function will available but before any output including headers sent?

Well hook your function on `init`. That will call when visiting site. If you want this hook only for admin area then it is `admin_init`.